# Understanding callback function parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been trying to understand callback functions and I'm unsure where the data variable/object is actually coming from in this example:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I think of this function being defined as something like this:

```
$.get = function(url, callback) {
  // send request to url
  callback(data); // execute callback function... but where is data coming from/being defined?
};
```

Comment: You guessed right and `data` is a variable created/populated by `$.get`. There is source viewer for jQuery but it's not trivial to read: http://www.james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to understand callback functions and I'm unsure where
>   the data variable/object is actually coming from in this example:

you invoked jquery function `$.get()` and gave a handle to your anonymous function as a parameter. jquery did all the work on invoking `ajax` methods, getting the `response` (data) and finally `invoke` your anonymous function (which you passed on to it as parameter). `data` variable is then passed on to this anonymous function by the same jquery function.